# Are there any disadvantages installing Ubuntu from Windows with Wubi?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, wubi

I will install Ubuntu on my machine on another HDD (an empty partition for Ubuntu). I will do this with Wubi to avoid having to burn a CD and is more practical at the moment. Is there any problem doing this?

With this approach, will I be unable to set the file system and partition for swap? Is there a problem installing this or not?

Answer (score 1):

There's a discussion on the pros and cons of Wubi on the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=481219&highlight=catch).  The downsides seem to be disk performance isn't as good as a regular installation, and there might be issues with standby/hibernation.

Regarding a partition for swap, you can create a swap file instead of a partition using [this guide](http://blog.mypapit.net/2007/07/how-to-add-linux-swap-file-if-you-dont-have-swap-partition.html).